# Expressing order or disorder mathematically

Tags: math

I work for game development company which makes casual games. One of the main casual genres is match-3: there is a field and chips of different colors. One should move chips so that they make lines of at least three chips of the same color. If the move leads to making a line the chips in the line disappear.

Chips on field can be located differently: there may be a lot of chips of the same color gouped in one place or there may be a situation when a player can't make a move - all the neighbour chips are of the different colors.

So, I want to express the situation on the field mathematically with a factor of order (disorder). If the factor is high a player can make a lot of matches and the lines made by the player are long. If the factor is low, the field is in complete disorder and one can't make a single match. This may be helpful for generating field of different difficulty.

The question is: what branch of math can help me to do this. Where should I start my research. Any suggestions for keywords to google?

Thanks in advace.

Comment: It also sounds like there is some aspect of percolation theory included in the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into graph theory.  You can for example make a graph, where nodes would be positions on the board, and two nodes would be connected with an edge if they are neighbours and have a chip of the same color. If you have large components with nodes of large degree, you have less disorder.  If all your components are small, you have high disorder.

Answer (score 4):

[Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29).

Comment: This seems to the thing I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is that you're looking at the distribution of `n` populations (one for each color), which I would approach with Poisson sampling,. You can use that to calculate the probability of finding two adjacent units of the same population (color), which will give you a measure of the difficulty of your puzzle.